# bootloader option not showing up, directly running ubuntu but i want windows too

Tags: dual-boot

I did the dual boot for windows 10 and ubuntu and installed ubuntu in a different drive, after restarting it, boot loader doesn't show up and it directly runs ubuntu. Now i dont have access to my windows. Windows is still available in my laptop (checked from "gparted"). How do i get it to show bootloader options when i start the laptop?

Comment: Did you install both in UEFI boot mode? Can you boot both from UEFI/BIOS boot menu? Is Windows fast startup/hibernation off?  Did you run `sudo update-grub` ? If still issues post this, it cannot fix Windows issues but may show details needed. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/